# Serial.read() to int

Tags: arduino, serial-port

What precisely is happening here when serial data is read in bytes into an int (it doesn't seem to be converted into an int) and then tested if it's identical to '1'? Why does it work? How is the if returning true? And what's the difference between '1' and "1" (aren't they both strings)?

```
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(2, 3);

void loop()
{
  if (bluetooth.available())
  {
    int number = bluetooth.read();

    //how is number (49 in bytes) identical to '1'
    if (number == '1')
    {
      Serial.print(number);
      Serial.print(" : ");
      Serial.println("on");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Learn C.  It is not python.

Comment: @TomServo many thanks for your helpful comment!

Answer (score 1):

A single value is read, and stored in `number`. The value is compared with the character *'1'*. 
In ASCII, the character *'1'* has a decimal value of 49.

I guess the example would have been more clear if the author declared `number` to be a `char` (or even `byte`) instead of an `int`.  I'm assuming that the `read()` only returns an 8-bit value.

For your last question: *"this is a string"* but *'z'* is a single character.

Comment: I sort of understand this but it still seems as if there is an extra conversion occurring that doesn't happen where you might expect it to (in the `read()` line) but does happen where it shouldn't (in the `if()`). Anyway I've resolved/simplified my problem by using `.readString()` instead. Thanks.

Comment: If you simplified your problem by using `.readString()` you should really have a look at character representations in C or you will have this problem again.

Comment: @theSealion I'll have a look. Thanks again.